# Is it possible to have url reference of an image in xaml like html?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox, rtf

I am working on RichTextBox in WPF and i would like to know if i can have url references something like we have in html

```
<img src="http://AnyWebsite.com/example.png" />
```

in xaml ( which i will be converting to rtf and storing it into the DB )

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible.

Based on your comment I am editing my earlier answer. This link will help you achieve what you want, you will need to create a custom converter class.

http://blog.davidsandor.com/post/2010/05/12/How-To-WPF-Databind-a-URL-URI-to-an-Image-control.aspx

Comment: thank you for the response but i am looking for independent references rather than an image in the project or resource

Comment: edited my answer, Kathy. Just see if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using FlowDocument instead of RichTextBox in this case as you want to display images and text togather.

For details you may refer to the [article in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx)